# OpenMP - Random running time - why having so high run-time variance?

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp, parallelism-amdahl

I am following **Tim Mattson**'s lectures on OpenMP to learn ways of implementation of some parallel programming concepts.

I was trying to observe the running time behavior of a parallel program that computes the value of **PI** using **3x10^8** steps.

Here is the code,

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stadio.h>

static long num_steps = 300000000;
double step;
#define PAD 8 // tried 50 too
#define NUM_THREADS 4
int main()
{
    int i, nthreads;
    double pi, sum[NUM_THREADS][PAD];
    double ts, te;

    ts = omp_get_wtime();

    step = 1.0/(double) num_steps;
    omp_set_num_threads(NUM_THREADS);
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        int i, id,nthrds;
        double x;

        id = omp_get_thread_num();
        nthrds = omp_get_num_threads();
        if (id == 0)  nthreads = nthrds;
        for (i=id, sum[id]=0.0;i< num_steps; i=i+nthrds) {
            x = (i+0.5)*step;
            sum[id][0] += 4.0/(1.0+x*x);
        }
    }

    for(i=0, pi=0.0;i<nthreads;i++)
        pi += sum[i][0] * step;

    te = omp_get_wtime();

    printf("%.10f\n", pi);
    printf("%.f\n", te-ts);

}
```

Now I was on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS running on a Dual Core machine. A call to **`omp_get_num_procs()`** returned **2**. The running time was something like totally random, ranging from 1.31 second to 4.46 seconds. Whereas the serial program was taking 2.31 second almost always.

I tried creating 1, 2, 3, 4, upto 10 threads. The running time varies too much in every case, though the average is smaller in case of more threads. I wasn't running any other applications.

---

**Can anyone explain why the running time varied too much?**

How to calculate the run time accurately? The lecturer has given the running time of his computer which seems consistent. And he was also using Dual Core processor.

Comment: What compile options did you use? Didi you compile with `-O3`?

Comment: You would require an affinity setting such as OMP_NUM_THREADS=2 OMP_PLACES=cores  (or proprietary equivalent, if using an old OpenMP).  Otherwise you don't maintain an even distribution of threads across cores.  By a possibly oversimplified analysis, running 2 threads placed randomly on 2 cores, without a smart OS scheduler, you will have both threads on one core 50% of the time and expect ideally 33% parallel speedup.  It won't be consistent run to run.

Comment: @tim18 Thank you for the insight. I am going to pick up the ideas soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Dual-CPU comparison, using OpenMP :

```
Result          : 3.1415926536
Number of CPU-s : 2  
Duration        : 2.4025482161
```

There seems to be pretty consistent set of resulting code-execution times:

```
/*           Duration        : 2.3984972970
             Duration        : 2.4004815188
             Duration        : 2.3814983589
             Duration        : 2.4070654172
             Duration        : 2.3964317020
             Duration        : 2.3858104548
             Duration        : 2.3765923560
             Duration        : 2.3734730321
    -O3:
             Duration        : 0.4159400249
             Duration        : 0.3089567909
             Duration        : 0.3106977220
             Duration        : 0.3312316008
             Duration        : 0.2856188160
             Duration        : 0.2984415500
             Duration        : 0.3282426349
             Duration        : 0.2836121118
                                    :......
  + FYI:     #pragma-overheads      :......
             Duration        : 0.0001377461                                                                                           
             Duration        : 0.0001228561
             Duration        : 0.0001215260
    REF:
    Amdahl's Law             >>> https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3
    criticism,
    on
    (not-)including also the real-world's infrastructure add-on
    { setup | termination }-overhead costs of #pragma omp parallel section
    ( 
      simplified test w/o the add-on costs of global OpenMP setup & configuration
      )

             */
```

which turns attention to your **S**ystem-**u**nder-**T**est workload background noise.

Best re-test your code on a head-less platform, so as to avoid any sort of GUI-related workloads from intervening the computing-part of the test.

May enjoy this [sandboxed **online**-TiO-**platform**](https://tio.run/##vVhbb@JWEH7nV4w26hZIjI/vNoRIbIIUKi4RIduHNEVeOMDRGtuyzYZVkr9eOsfm4oRsMQnpPBhkz8z55j72QBgPBovFEXMHzmxI4dSb@qXJGbyFRBFa51/r5fWNs7MzmESRH5ZFMYzswXfvBw1GjndfGnhT0RZVyzRNS1FFRdd1yTJyGxhhNGTe24AgjFrronbZ/D2EZu3P8g4YAf3BQua5oSiZiqHqsiUquRzyRWwAjueOwZ1N@2FE/RCqoJAlVXJDb/bNocCfVHJHQzpiLoWr2sUaiPk6uChgdAgagcjz1nLtm1a/d9mt1y6uQc0xN4Kpzdx8IfeAQjkuiYHphzTqczTRJKD2MMynpAqVXMy2ROWzEwhn09sUx90tgrurpLmi8AQimtziZ/KfE3CX6pP78YUbidZLJSLmE9nCxi3Lk6MQL9UY5xhx3kdsSvOFCjdZyE6Pm7@nqN4Oov5ZDg5ACAPpMdZ15Af2eGpzrODbge041FnyPGYgzldEAqhNh/bEEZr2PXRaVwLGZ@bHJzy8Hy0/aW35JjpsmEQI4/NGXcvgzysHwHVQG4fxzyaFkjzkGc/zaC9diYdSutJls0PZh9o4gjw3tFoFAgVY1xoi3RnUdAYfFJdYhFveue@Ed9FKyR@dL0uMxQP6rggjL@DO2zBU42LYR9fLezgBhrQU4agZlGW9LBtloEHgBWWww5CN3SnFuos8oHM/oCEfE3DPognYQWD/hOinT6FcfmEsb7tseHdL7hAgKZHKewDGNrMqt3Opt8pVstNU@wV8fpxkTwEedrqewSmkpfdAs0V/7x9oxsMGx6sKRcRbgU5oDulI52MhUtJQopgM3WzIfx2d4yqoJQIi6sbBhtrnyDWH17rDS4RPB0zrA5ceFMUP6BAi3CZL1buApucl34RoiNU1oTwo4I0wE@IBCo/4JJgyF1cwLLgnYeCFuFzsd9TaB8/KkQ0rb/DB1pZ7c92Diw7U4BynfqNZ78JNW@jWW52vtS/NOnyGdqctXF92ur3zm158q9VoN1q1ZuO61ziP5QWU71zVu7Veo9NeO1k4AP3fTn76b@dlWabmSFvL1AoePeT6t@4IEX3/rpraVk/7uMazcILLaqx@M6twBpykLPAZrMZC0ohXyzaw42MoPOfEDhWnb5y9y66X6PcD3AhHefjUpeHMiTZSZfitJJHRX@6nE66hUHnO3p5Nv9GA58H51Y0QcnbcumLuZ6uSH3gDXJS25C9mQZIwrxwXUQEzKH4REVMDYVtELimWqVqGbBnkeXBf41UJUU1Jk0xzN69iSvhSqWimlUWvQXRNlQw5g15LVxXJIDLJgkEzJaJqaha8hq5ZsqLpWfQaimooRJGlmFfoKOVdQqSkSpqFDpRVazevQkxL0w2LZOGViG4ZhrzbIcirSLIi6YSYu3llU9Mx0pKeQa@MSYT2aSQLBtmUVVlXsvhBNhVdkiVJMpNaWzYm/jkBW9Or744hHcRaftVc@ReHCZY5JF02D/eiFzfljk/d1hWMHe@b7SyFPyOXO2LjFbRCef8vKTuNJIRIimGougQfSG/49JIJuRznSUZeSZMxnWJm3I2eFot/BiPHHocLYeSh@6f@AmvpXw) to re-run experiments.